# Is it possible to find out what kind of things is being loaded slowly in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I load some page, chrome tab shows this loading sign for a long time (2 or 3 minutes).

[image]

I suspect some javascript package or css used by that page caused this.

Is it possible to find out what kind of things is being loaded slowly in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I highly recommend [Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).  It is a very powerful tool that can *lots* of different things, including timing HTTP requests to see what is taking a page so long to load.